# Javascript don't work after refreshing the page - WHY?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have 3 sliders, each has 1 Youtube video.

Each video has custom made START / STOP javascript buttons.

My script works perfectly when the page is loaded the first time. AFTER refresh, the javascript buttons don't work anymore. In fact, they will not work until I clear cache and often I even need to restart browser.

Thank you for any tip!

```js
// START STOP YOUTUBE VIDEO

   // Inject YouTube API script
     var tag = document.createElement('script');
     tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
     var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    
    // Set global variable for the player
      var playerA;
      var playerB;
      var playerC;

    // this function gets called when API is ready to use
     function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
       
       // create the global player from the specific iframe (#video)
       
       // for Slider 1
          playerA = new YT.Player('player1', {
            events: {
              // call this function when player is ready to use
              'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
          });

       // for Slider 2
          playerB = new YT.Player('player2', {
            events: {
              // call this function when player is ready to use
              'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
          });

       // for Slider 3
          playerC = new YT.Player('player3', {
            events: {
              // call this function when player is ready to use
              'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
          });
     
     };

 // Bind Events
     function onPlayerReady(event) {
       
      // bind Slider 1 events

        var playButton = document.getElementById("VideoPlayBtn1");
        playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
          playerA.playVideo();
        });
        
        var pauseButton = document.getElementById("VideoPauseBtn1");
        pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
          playerA.pauseVideo();
        });


      // bind Slider 2 events
        
        var playButton = document.getElementById("VideoPlayBtn2");
        playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
          playerB.playVideo();
        });
        
        var pauseButton = document.getElementById("VideoPauseBtn2");
        pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
          playerB.pauseVideo();
        });

      // bind Slider 3 events
        
        var playButton = document.getElementById("VideoPlayBtn3");
        playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
          playerB.playVideo();
        });
        
        var pauseButton = document.getElementById("VideoPauseBtn3");
        pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
          playerB.pauseVideo();
        });
        
  };
```

```html
<iframe id="player1" class="VideoA" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="0"></iframe>

<button id="VideoPlayBtn1" >Play</button></div>
<button id="VideoPauseBtn1">Pause</button></div>

<iframe id="player1" class="VideoA" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="0"></iframe>


<button id="VideoPlayBtn2" >Play2</button></div>
<button id="VideoPauseBtn2">Pause2</button></div>

<iframe id="player3" class="VideoA" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="0"></iframe>

<button id="VideoPlayBtn3" >Play3</button></div>
<button id="VideoPauseBtn3">Pause3</button></div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet is also not working.

Comment: Ok, I solved the issue. The  "// Inject YouTube API script" bit had to be placed in a separate script and load later.

Answer (score -1):

You can refresh page by implementing following code in java script

Use location.reload(); method.

For more info refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)